# Reactjs Server side rendering with Redux store is not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux, server-side-rendering

I have followed the tutorial https://github.com/morinokami/react-ssr for implementing serverside rendering(SSR) for my react js website.
My website is using redux-store for storing global states. But when I implemented SSR, I am stuck with the following errors

> Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a Provider

I am adding my index.js and App.js Code below

index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from './store'
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

App.js

```
const App = () => {
return ( 
    <Router>
        <div className="content-wrapper">          
        <Switch>          
          <Route path='/login'                component={LoginScreen} />
          <Route path='/register'             component={RegisterScreen} />
        </Switch>
        </div>
    </Router>
}
```

My server side rendering code is as follows

```
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import express from 'express';

import App from '../src/App';

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3006;
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const app =  ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<App />);
  const indexFile = path.resolve('./build/index.html');

  fs.readFile(indexFile, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Something went wrong:', err);
      return res.status(500).send('Oops, better luck next time!');
    }

    return res.send(
      data.replace('<div id="root"></div>', `<div id="root">${app}</div>`)
    );
  });
});

app.use(express.static('./build'));

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Note, I have also tried moving Provider to App.js But it doesn't work , Can someone help me to fix this issue?

Comment: Try this  `const app = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  );`

Comment: It doesn't work!  Struck with same error